Comparing two sequences of events for similarity
Suppose I have two sequences of unequal lengths whose elements are timestamps of discrete events in milliseconds: $S_1 = \{150, 200, 700, 1300, 2500\}$, $S_2 = \{300, 670, 900, 1300\}$. These sequences could represent two people clapping their hands and we could ask how well-synchronized their clapping is.
How could I devise a "distance" (not necessarily obeying the triangle inequality) metric for measuring this? $d(S_1, S_2)=0$ if $S_1$ is perfectly aligned to $S_2$ and the larger $d(S_1, S_2)$ is the worse the misalignment.
The reason I'm asking is because I've read a paper in which $d(S_1, S_2)$ is defined as the L2 norm of the difference of the Gaussian convolutions of $S_1$ and $S_2$. So is this a standard method or could there be better ways to measure misalignment?

This will be a bit of a non-answer, but I think it is relevant here.

could there be better ways to measure misalignment?

Whenever you use terms like "better" or "best", you need to define specifically what criteria or metric you are using to decide what "better" means.
In your case there are many different ways a distance metric could be constructed. Whether one is better than another really depends on what you want to do with the distance. For example: are 4 exact matches better or worse than 5 almost matches ? Say we have
$$ d_1 = d(\{100,200,300, 400, 500\},\{100,300, 400, 500\}) \\ 
d_2 = d(\{100,200,300, 400, 500\},\{98, 220, 305, 400, 488\})$$
Should $d_1 > d_2$ or the other way around? These are simply different "types of misalignment" and how you weigh them depends on how sensitive your application is to them.
This sounds nit-picky, but it is fundamental. Creating the correct requirements and metrics is actually the more difficult work. Once that's properly defined, coding it up tends to be straight forward.
Typically this type of work starts with a use case analysis. Identify a few typical examples and few edge cases and then try to determine why the distance in case A should be bigger or smaller than in case B. From there you can develop one or more algorithm that follow the same line of thinking.
